# MongoDB aggregation $group queryquery

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in which documents are like

```
{
    "_id" : "api",
    "titleAndTimeDetails" : [ 
        {
            "Title" : "api data",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(8091446063)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "class data",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(519163710)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "API or datasets for age world",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(34245103)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "What does a null result mean API?",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(171605137)
        }
 ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "government",
    "titleAndTimeDetails" : [ 
        {
            "Title" : "Is there an open standard for the CAFR (Comprehensive Annual Finance Report)?",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(574587563)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "College Scorecard full data base",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(9422714)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "List of German local politicians",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(691311396)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "Trying to extrapolate patient costs by physician from public Medicare pricing data",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(9590779130)
        }, 
        {
            "Title" : "Are there good examples of open read-write APIs in Federal government?",
            "timeTaken" : NumberLong(1784634763)
        } 
   ]
}
```

The query statement is to display the `Title` for each "_id" which has minimum time taken. Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You should first [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `titleAndTimeDetails` then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by `titleAndTimeDetails.timeTaken` and finally [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `_id` and get $first of `Title`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$titleAndTimeDetails" },
    { $sort: { "titleAndTimeDetails.timeTaken": 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", title: { $first: "$titleAndTimeDetails.Title" } } }
])
```

Comment: $unwind is a costly operation for this scenario, we can use $project and $min in the aggregation pipeline to get the desired result. Please see my answer.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath, I like your query more. But cost of unwind is not high if you not directly project the multiplied documents(which we don't in this situation). Both for mine and your query, costly part is `sort` ($min uses sort too). So it is negligible. your query has a better readability though

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: { timeTaken:{$min:"$titleAndTimeDetails.
timeTaken"}}}])
```

The result which we get for the sample documents given in the question, is as shown below

```
{ "_id" : "api", "timeTaken" : NumberLong(34245103) }
{ "_id" : "government", "timeTaken" : NumberLong(9422714) }
```

To get the desired result [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) of the aggregation pipeline are used

Comment: Thanks a lot:) it worked. Query is executing fine now. I missed this sort functionality